# API Error UNAUTHORIZED on Crypto.com exchange

Tags: api, ccxt, crypto.com-exchange-api

When i use api method private/create-withdrawal on crypto.com exchange i get error: "code":10002,"message":"UNAUTHORIZED".
I am using this request with axios:

```
url: 'https://api.crypto.com/v2/private/create-withdrawal',
  method: 'post',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  data: '{"id":"1679053143058","method":"private/create-withdrawal","params":{
"currency":"1INCH",
"amount":"25",
"address":"********",
"network_id":"ETH"},
"api_key":"********",
"sig":"*********",
"nonce":"1679053143058"}'
}
```

Parametr sig is in lower case. I also used method that creates signature in method private/get-currency-networks (with empty params) and it worked.
How to fix this?

```
url: 'https://api.crypto.com/v2/private/create-withdrawal',
  method: 'post',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  data: '{"id":"1679053143058","method":"private/create-withdrawal","params":{"currency":"1INCH","amount":"25","address":"********","network_id":"ETH"},"api_key":"********","sig":"*********","nonce":"1679053143058"}'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem. You need to text to cryptocom support and ask to activate withdraw function (it`s disabled by default).

Comment: How did you contact them? Email or chat? Trying to reach support but they do not answer

Comment: Best is to use the chat function within the mobile app. Emailing them is just a waste of time.